# DevExpress - Ajax form return null object

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

i work with Ajax.BeginForm

```
@model Shared.DataContracts.ConfigurationTransports
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "ConfigurationTransports",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{
   Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ConfigurationTransports/ConfigurationPartialContent.cshtml", Model);
}
```

And my easy form

```
@model Shared.DataContracts.ConfigurationTransports

@Html.DevExpress().Label(s =>
{
    s.Name = "Id";
    s.ClientVisible = false;
}).Bind(Model.Id).GetHtml()


@Html.DevExpress().CheckBox(settings =>
{

settings.Name = "checkBoxUseStop";
settings.Properties.ValueUnchecked = 0;
settings.Properties.ValueChecked = 1;
settings.Text = Resources.UseStops;
}).Bind(Model.UseStop).GetHtml()



@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
 {
 settings.Name = "btnSave";
 settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
 }).GetHtml()
```

When I click save a post to method Save and parameter ConfigurationTransports is empty without value, but if i load my form i have there values from my send object.

```
 public ActionResult Save(ConfigurationTransports transport)
    {
        //Some logic method
        return View("Index", preprava.GetData());
    }
```

I read a lot of topic on devexpress forum, but i cant find solution.
Do you have any idea?
thx

Answer (score 0):

decorate your Action with **[HttpPost]** Annotation

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ConfigurationTransports transport)
{
    //Some logic method
    return View("Index", preprava.GetData());
}
```

Comment: Yes forgot it, but still have problem with it.

Comment: check for the HTML output if it contains the proper names for the model fields